# Correct mongo index for a large query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and have a schema similar to this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    created: Date,
    fieldA: ObjectId,
    fieldB: ObjectId,
    fieldC: ObjectId,
    sortField: Number
});
```

This is a big collection so I want to make sure the indexes are optimal. I build up a query with something like this:

```
var query = Schema.find({created: some-date-clause});
if ( some-condition )
    query = query.or({fieldA: {$in: listOfSomeFieldAIDs}});
if ( some-other-condition )
    query = query.or({fieldB: {$in: listOfSomeFieldBIDs}});
if ( yet-another-condition )
    query = query.or({fieldC: {$in: listOfSomeFieldCIDs}});

query = query.sort({sortField:-1});
```

I want to make sure that whatever the query is, it's fully covered. My instinct is to create an index that spans created, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC and sortField. But should I actually create several indices for the situations where for example only the second condition is true, or the first and the third are true? Should I be approaching this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each clause of an `$or` query is considered independently, so it's likely best to create three separate indexes, one per `fieldA`, `fieldB`, and `fieldC`.  See docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes).

The sort occurs after the results of the three `$or` clauses are merged, so adding `sortField` to these indexes isn't likely to be useful.

But as always, validate any index approach using [explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) to make sure your queries are able to use the indexes you've created.